# Mongomapper human readable id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

Is there any way to create human readable id for mongomapper
I mean replace `54114ac51d41c84fb900005a` to id `1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

### [gem 'mongomapper_id2'](https://github.com/phstc/mongomapper_id2)

It’s a MongoMapper’s plugin to add `auto incremented ids` in MongoMapper’s documents.

Example:

```
# app/models/movie.rb
class Movie
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :title, String 

  # Here is the mongomapper_id2
  auto_increment!
end

movie = Movie.create(:title => 'The Simpsons Movie')
movie.id # BSON::ObjectId('4d1d150d30f2246bc6000001') 

# Here is the mongomapper_id2
movie.id2
# => 1

movie2 = Movie.create(:title => 'Pirates of Silicon Valley')

movie2.id2
# => 2
```